# js button not updating innerhtml

Tags: javascript, html

I have looked at numerous questions already on here and I haven't been able to find a similar problem. I am trying to give a button a function that updates a variable (specifically a number, i.e. - button press >> `0` becomes `1`) and write it to the `innerHTML` of a `div`. It updates in an alert, but it doesn't update the `innerHTML`.

```
var example = 0;
var exampleDiv = document.getElementById('exampleDiv');

function buyExample() {
  example += 1;
}

exampleDiv.innerHTML = 'You have ' + example + ' examples.';
```

The number displayed on the webpage is 0.

Comment: Can you provide your html code?

Comment: You probably want `exampleDiv.innerHTML = ...` to be inside the `buyExample` function, but you haven't really shared enough code for anyone to be sure.

Comment: you have to provide the whole code to be sure, but you can't expect that exampleDiv.innerHTML is updated just because you have incremented "example".  Most probably, you also have to set exampleDiv.innerHTML inside the buyExample() function.

Comment: You never invoke `buyExample`, so it is never increased.

Comment: `exampleDiv.innerHTML = 'You have ' + example + ' examples.';` goes inside buyExample() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code based on my comment above:

```js
var example = 0;
var exampleDiv = document.getElementById('exampleDiv');

function buyExample() {
  example += 1;
  exampleDiv.innerHTML = 'You have ' + example + ' example' + (example !== 1 ? 's' : '') + '.';
}

document.getElementById("incrementButton").onclick = buyExample;
```

```html
<button id="incrementButton">Click me</button>

<div id="exampleDiv">You have 0 examples.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working properly since `exampleDiv.innerHTML` is set only once. You have to move it to the function.

```js
var example = 0;
var exampleDiv = document.getElementById('exampleDiv');
render();

function buyExample() {
  example += 1;
  render();
}

function render() {
  exampleDiv.innerHTML = 'You have ' + example + ' examples.';
}
```

```html
<button id="button" onclick="buyExample()">Button</button>

<div id="exampleDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the context you've given, your statement:

```
exampleDiv.innerHTML = 'You have ' + example + ' examples.';
```

Will only run once when the Javascript initializes, at which point the *example* variable is still set to 0. If you want the div to update every time you use the button, it needs to be included in the *buyExample()* method as well.

```
function buyExample() {
    example += 1;
    exampleDiv.innerHTML = 'You have ' + example + ' examples.';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the statement that updates the DOM into the function that runs each time the button is clicked. The way you have it, the `innerHTML` is set once when the page loads and the variable `example` gets updated on each click, but you never set the value of `example` to the page again.

```js
var example = 0;
var exampleDiv = document.getElementById('exampleDiv');

function buyExample() {
  example += 1;
  exampleDiv.innerHTML = 'You have ' + example + ' examples.';
}
```

```html
<div id="exampleDiv">You have 0 examples.</div>
<button onclick="buyExample()">buy</button>
```